# How to read POST parameters in Minimal API, in C# posted by desktop app, .NET 6.0?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, desktop-application, minimal-apis

I am trying to build a small desktop app (.NET 6.0) that gets data from .NET 6.0 minimal API server.

The API server code is:

```
//app.MapPost("/show/", async Task<string> (string myName) =>
app.MapPost("/show/", async Task<string> (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    //return await Task.FromResult(myName);
    return await Task.FromResult(request.Query["myName"]);
});
```

The postman is able to post to

```
http://127.0.0.1:5400/show?myName=Srikanth S
```

and gets a reply in the uncommented as well as commented version.

The desktop app's response object has

> StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error'

after the call to

```
app.MapPost("/show/", async Task<string> (string myName)
```

version while it responds with

> StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request'

in the response object and

> Required parameter "string myName" was not provided from query string

on result object.

My desktop app has this simple code only

```
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        content.Add("myName", "Srikanth S");

        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5400/show", new FormUrlEncodedContent(content));
            string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            Debug.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
```

I tried the permutation, combinations of `StringContent`, `FormUrlEncodedContent`, `Dictionary`, `KeyvaluePair` ...;

It looks like it is not capturing 'myName' in the `HttpRequest` version.

Any guidance or solution please?

update: created new .net core web api project (weatherforecast sample), added

```
app.MapPost("/show/", (string myName) =>
{
    return myName;
});
```

as well as tried

```
app.MapPost("/show/", async (string myName) =>
{
    return await Task.FromResult(myName);
});
```

No changes in Desktop App, I get this in debug output as below

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Required parameter "string myName" was not provided from query string.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.Log.RequiredParameterNotProvided(HttpContext httpContext, String parameterTypeName, String parameterName, String source, Boolean shouldThrow)
   at lambda_method2(Closure , Object , HttpContext )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.RequestDelegateFactory.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<Create>b__0(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Host: 127.0.0.1:5145
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 17
```

any help is highly appreciated. For background, i am using visual studio 2022 community edition Version 17.3.6
, dotnet 6.0.402

SOS

Comment: Seems like you are confusing parameters from query string and body content, make some research on the difference.

Comment: Try just:  app.MapPost("/show", async (string myName) on minimal API, leave desktop app as is.

Comment: Please have a look at the update

Comment: Here at https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/ff1addd02d239d2d26f4648a06158727#parameter-binding says post parameters are processed as json from body. all the code examples are similar to the code I am already trying. Is there an explicit way to post parameters as body data? Or is that postasync is already sending in body ? Any pointers or guidance please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [image]

When using Postman to check the API method, you can see the parameter is added to the request URL.

> ```
> Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
> content.Add("myName", "Srikanth S");
>
> using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
> {
>     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5400/show", new  FormUrlEncodedContent(content));
>     string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
>     Debug.WriteLine(result);
> }
> ```

But in the desktop app, the parameter is added to the request body, so in this scenario, the API method can't find the value from the request URL, so the value is null and will throw an exception.

To solve this issue, **you can try to send the parameter via the Query String**: add the parameter at the end of the request URL, like this:

```
    var name = "Srikanth S";
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync($"http://127.0.0.1:5400?myName={name}", null);
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

the API method:

```
app.MapPost("/show/", async Task<string> (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    //return await Task.FromResult(myName);
    return await Task.FromResult(request.Query["myName"]);
});
```

**Or you can send the parameter from request body**:
in the API method, you can get the parameter from the Form. Modify the API method as below:

```
app.MapPost("/show/", async Task<string> (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    //return await Task.FromResult(myName);
    return await Task.FromResult(request.Form["myName"]); //get value from form.
});
```

In this time, the HttpClient method like this:

```
   Dictionary<string, string> content = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    content.Add("myName", "Srikanth S");

    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5400/show", new FormUrlEncodedContent(content));
        string result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Debug.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Refer to the following screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zhi. I was struggling with this for almost a week :(
Only I could have read your answer before ! I will try with request.Form method as above. Thanks a lot for explaining.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you all for the guidance and help. Finally I cracked it :)
Hope this will be useful to everyone. The key is ***post data is to be read from the request body on the api server***. Here is how I did it

```
app.MapPost("/show/", async (HttpRequest request) =>
{
    var body = new StreamReader(request.Body);
    string postData = await body.ReadToEndAsync();
    Dictionary<string, dynamic> keyValuePairs = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(postData) ?? new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();
    // here after you can play as you like :)
    return await Task.FromResult<string>(postData);
});
```

My desktop app code

```
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();

            using StringContent jsonContent = new(
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(new {myName = "Srikanth S"}), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("http://127.0.0.1:5145/show", jsonContent);

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            // here after you can play as you like :)
            Debug.WriteLine(jsonResponse);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter of [PostAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.postasync?view=net-6.0#system-net-http-httpclient-postasync(system-string-system-net-http-httpcontent)) is meant for the **body**, not query string data.  Just add the **myName** query parameter to the URL.

```cs
HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsync(
    "http://127.0.0.1:5400/show?myName=Jose", // <----- Like this
    new FormUrlEncodedContent(content)
);
```

Comment: Thank you Jose. This I could guess already and use that as last resort. What happens if i need to send large data ? is there a limitation of total data length.
Also, all the examples on stackcoverflow and elsewhere show parameters being sent as content only. Can you clarify where I am misunderstanding ? Thank you.

Comment: If you want to send more data, use the body, but then in your server code, do not use `Query`, use `Form` or read the body yourself.